# How could I send email from users who are logged in to admin?

Tags: python, html, django, email

I am working on a project to send the withdraw request from `user` who is logged in to `admin`. In this case I don't have to send mail to users instead I will have to send mail to admin official email address for notification. I used `reply_to`, but it showed me that it is `unexpected argument`

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def withdraw(request):
    form_class = WithdrawBalance
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.owner = request.user
        obj.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your request has been submitted.')
        send_mail('New Withdrawal Request',
            'Hello there, A new withdrawal request has been received.',
            request.user.email, ['bilalkhangood4@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = form_class()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'nextone/withdraw.html', context)
```

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'bilalkhangood4@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 587
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Comment: Does gmail not require a password to be specified?

Comment: I have not specified password in stackoverflow.

Comment: OK - it looked like it was missing completely, which would have explained any issues :) Does it work if you use SSL on port 465 instead of TLS?

Comment: I used 465 in ```EMAIL_PORT``` but it gave me ```SMTPServerDisconnected at /withdraw/
Connection unexpectedly closed```

Comment: Did you use 465 and set `EMAIL_USE_SSL = True` and `EMAIL_USE_TLS = False`?

Comment: Now it is received and saying that it is received from admin to admin email address, which is ```bilalkhangood4@gmail.com```. Although I used ```request.user.email```.

Comment: Please check the below answer also. It is somehow right but I have explained that it is not notifying the admin that a user has sent requested withdrawal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to provide `reply_to` argument, then you need to use [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects).

Try this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage(
    subject='New Withdrawal Request',
    body='Hello there, A new withdrawal request has been received.',
    from_email='bilalkhangood4@example.com',
    to=[request.user.email],
    reply_to=['another@example.com'],
)

email.send()
```

Comment: That is working fine but here is one problem. When email is received to admin, it gives me that it is from admin email to user email. I interchanged bilalkhangood4@gmail.com with ```to``` and ```request.user.email``` with ```from_email```. After sending it gave me that it is from admin to admin.

Comment: I want to notify admin if user requests for withdrawal.

Comment: I think that's simply because the emails in `form_email` and `to` need to be swapped ...

Comment: I swapped it but it is giving me message that it is received from admin to admin.

Comment: @Housi  are you using 2 different accounts for testing? so you want to send email from request.user.email to admin@mail.com, then you need to place from_email=request.user.email and to=admin@mail.com. If this is what you are  doing then it should work in this case.